# nopCommerce 3.2 plugin isn't working on nopCommerce 3.3 after configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I developed a plugin for nopCommerce 3.2 using third rule of this [link](http://www.pronopcommerce.com/3-ways-to-display-views-in-your-nopcommerce-plugins-embedded-resource-theme-override-and-custom-view-engine)

On nopCommerce 3.3 I created a new project,added references, copied all Models,Controllers, ViewEngines, Contents, Scripts, RouteProvider and Description. But whenever I am building that project it showing some errors regarding Nop.Admin, Nop.Core, Nop.Data, Nop.Services and all other libraries about Nop.*

I removed and added them again, but same problem is occurring each time.

Here is a picture about those errors.[image]

What are causing that kind of errors and how can those be removed?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with references. My suggestion is open some NOP plugin project file as xml and check your project file (again as xml) if the references are **same**.

You have to check third party libraries if they are in correct folder. The version of the library is part of the path:

for example: `..\..\packages\Autofac.3.3.1\lib\net40\Autofac.dll`

I remember the same problem when I moved from 2.xx to 3.10.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove all your links and add them again using

References -> Add reference.. -> Browse -> Browse... -> Make sure that the path points to your current solution -> add references manually

Answer (score 0):

My bet is that your plugin is targeting wrong .NET version, go into project properties and change target framework to 4.5.1. Also when adding references to

```
System.Web.Mvc
System.Web.WebPages
```

Make sure you are targeting ones bundled with NopCommerce, or you can get them via NuGet.

Answer (score 0):

try to check the build, the output of the build and check the properties of the referenced assembly if is able to copy to local (if you are building the project in the bin )or not (if you are building it to the plugins folder).

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the Nop references (Nop.Admin, Nop.Core, Nop.Data...) by browsing to Presentation/Nop.Web/bin?

Or you are adding through solution? (see screenshot)?

[image: Adding reference to nopCommerce libraries]

You should really be using the latter. :)